# Why does official prefer concantane than hstack/vstack in Numpy?

Tags: numpy

I find that the latest documentation about `hstack`/`vstack` note that "you should prefer `np.concatenate` or `np.stack`".

But I think their readability is better than `concatenate(a, 0)` or `concatenate(a, 1)`

Answer (score 3):

All 3 'stack' functions use `concatenate` (as does `np.append` and `column_stack`).  It's instructive to look at their code.  `np.source(np.hstack)` for example.

What they all do is massage the dimensions of the input arrays, making sure they are are 1d or 2d etc, and then call `concatenate` with the appropriate `axis`.  So in the long run it's a good idea to know how to use `concatenate` without the 'crutch' of the others.

But people will continue to use `hstack` and `vstack` where convenient.  `dstack` and `column_stack` are less common.  `np.append` is frequently misused and should be banished.

I think this 'preferred' note was added when `np.stack` was added.  `np.stack` also uses `concatenate`, but in a somewhat more sophisticated way.  It inserts a new axis (with `expand_dims`).  I view it as a generalization of `np.array`.  When given a list of matching arrays, `np.array` joins them on a new initial axis.  `np.stack` does the same thing as a default, but lets us specify a different 'new' axis for concatenation.

I should qualify my answer.  It is not official.  Rather I'm making an educated guess based on knowledge of the code.