# how to append a array to a np.array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

```
coordinates =  np.empty([0,5])
np.vstack(  (coordinates,  np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ))
print coordinates  # []
np.append(coordinates, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), axis=0)
print coordinates
```

In the code shown above, I tried to append the array, but both approaches failed. In the first approach, the output is still empty, in the second approach, the output is an error saying

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

What is wrong with my method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44448999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the results of `numpy.vstack()`

From the ([Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html))

> numpy.vstack(arrays, axis=0)
>
> Returns:
>
> stacked : ndarray

#### Test Code:

```
coordinates = np.empty([0, 5])
x = np.vstack((coordinates, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
print x
```

#### Results:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]]
```